# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'FloatVector'

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am new to Python and even newer to rpy2, which allows me to work with R via Python.

I tried to import r from rpy2:

```
    from rpy2.robjects import r
```

This seemed to work and I continued with my code, which at some point contains something similar to:

```
    pval=1.0-r.phyper(integerA, integerB, integerC, integerD)
```

Which gave the following error:

```
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'FloatVector'
```

What does this mean and how can I change it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This means that you can't subtract a vector (i.e. an ordered collection of numbers) from a single number.

Answer (score 0):

The result of

```
r.phyper(integerA, integerB, integerC, integerD)
```

is an R vector of floats (hence the rpy2 objects `FloatVector`). You may see it better by running:

```
print(r.phyper(integerA, integerB, integerC, integerD))
```

Now if you want to apply an R vectorized operator (here `"-"` applied to all elements in your vector) one of the easiest way is to work with R vectors for both operands and use the "R Operator" accessor `.ro`:

```
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import FloatVector
p = FloatVector((.6, .7, .99))

pval= FloatVector([1.0])).ro - p
```

One of the alternatives is do it the way element-wise operation on Python sequences are usually done:

```
pval = [1.0 - x for x in p]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That already clarifies it a lot. However, I thought the phyper would just give me a 'p-value' or 'chance', which I had expected to be one number.

Comment: When I apply the above, I turn my number 1.0 into a FloatVector, I guess? What does that mean (as in, what does my '1.0' become by doing that)? What is the meaning of the FloatVector function (I googled, but can't find a clear explanation)? And how do I obtain a single p-value from substracting two FloatVectors?

Comment: @Myrtille "what does my '1.0' become by doing that" : 1.0 is no longer a scalar (that is "just a number") but a sequence (specifically an R vector). The documentation on readthedocs is unfortunately partial because the docstrings are not properly extracted from the Python objects. There is a bit here ( http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/vector.html?highlight=FloatVector#creating-vectors ), and the docstring is in the source (https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/1e2a3c9333bc8d6c9c1c0ec7e53e6f1541841967/rpy/robjects/vectors.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#vectors.py-441)

Answer (score 0):

I think I made it work similarly to what Igautier suggested, but instead of turning my 1.0 into a FloatVector as well, I turned the FloatVector into a float, as the FloatVector seemed to contain 1 element only:

```
    p = r.phyper(intA, intB, intC, intD)
    p = float(p[0])
    pval = 1.0 - p
```

Thanks for your help!